# Не работают пользовательские функции "безопасной" загрузки картинки в SFML/C++

Tags: c++, sfml

Требовалось сделать возможность загружать графические файлы с помощью своей функции, которая бы предотвращала спам в консоль если нужного файла не было по указанному пути и подставляла другой .png файл вместо отсутствующего. Функции выглядят вот так:

SafeLoadFromFile.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics/Texture.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Image.hpp>
#include <String>
#include <fstream>

void SafeLoadTextureFromFile(sf::Texture texture, std::string inputPath) {
    
    std::string validPath = "src/resources/textures/error_missing.png";
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(inputPath);

    if (file) validPath = inputPath;

    file.close();

    texture.loadFromFile(validPath);

}

void SafeLoadImageFromFile(sf::Image image, std::string inputPath) {

    std::string validPath = "src/resources/textures/error_missing.png";
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(inputPath);

    if (file) validPath = inputPath;

    file.close();

    image.loadFromFile(validPath);

}
```

SafeLoadFromFile.h:

```
#ifndef SAFELOADTEXTUREFROMFILE_H
#define SAFELOADTEXTUREFROMFILE_H

extern void SafeLoadTextureFromFile(sf::Texture texture, std::string path);
extern void SafeLoadImageFromFile(sf::Image image, std::string inputPath);

#endif
```

При попытке загрузки в тестовые переменные они остаются пустыми (тестировал через `std::cout << TestImage.getSize().x << " " << TestImage.getSize().y;`). Никаких ошибок я не получаю, метод `loadFromFile` в функции возвращает true, а переменная все равно остается пустой.

В чем здесь может быть проблема?

Comment: Да у вас же делается копия при передачи в функции. Передавайте их по ссылке.

Comment: @こきん можно, пожалуйста, немного конкретнее? Копия чего создается?

Comment: Копия первого параметра, он создаётся на стекле, и при выходе из функции уничтожается.